# Java Downloading file from .txt placed on URL and unzip that file in specify destination

Tags: auto-update

How can i make that after when you press button named "BUTTOR" it will download a .zip file to specify location and unzip a .zip file from .txt placed on URL to specify location, and in my .txt i will have for example line in other URL where zip folder is uploaded for example in my .txt file placed on "http://mysite/update.txt" there will be on the first line "number" and on the second line "http://mysite/download.zip". 
And there will be making a file in specify destination folder named "version.txt" where i will have that "number" which was in previous .txt file And during that process i will get information on my label named "info_info" how many percent left to end of download. 
And after that process i will get info on my "info_info" that i need to press button one more time to for example say pop up another window which say "HELLO".

And when i will open one more time that program it will check if i have the same "number" in my "version.txt" like in "update.txt" in the first line, if yes than program will say on "info_info" laber to press butoon to start, if the "number" in my "version.txt" is different than number in "update.txt" it will delete all old files and download new one from "update.txt" url which is inside on the second line. AAfter that it will say to press button to for example say "Hello".

Sorry for my english but i am still learning that language. I hope that someone understand me.